# move element with keypress (multiple)

Tags: jquery, keypress

Diagonal move not working and issue on left-longPress/right simultaneous

But on double keypress the ship goes crazy!

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
    var box = $("#plane"),
        left = 37,
        up = 38,
        right = 39,
        down = 40

    if (e.keyCode == left) {
        box.animate({left: "-=5000"},3000);
    }
    if (e.keyCode == up) {
        box.animate({top: "-=5000"},3000);
    }
    if (e.keyCode == right) {
        box.animate({left:"+=5000"},3000);
    }
    if (e.keyCode == down) {
        box.animate({top: "+=5000"},3000);
    }
});
$(document).bind('keyup', function() {
    $('#plane').stop();
});
```

Comment: +1! GRrreat comment! :D hehe I almost spit my coffee!

Comment: glad to make you happy. I'll try something when i come back from my lunch

Comment: I'm working on it already! (hate google sometimes) Let me know when you're full!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relying on keyboard events to move an element will make it dependent on the OS key-interval delay. **Instead, use the game interval and check the pressed keys stored inside an Object**

On `keydown keyup` events, if the keyCode returned by `event.which` is `>=37 && <=40` means arrow keys were used. Store inside a `K` (keys) Object a boolean  value for key-number property.

#### Interval:

Inside a `window.requestAnimationFrame` increase or decrease the `x`, `y` position of your element if a key-number property (inside our `K` object) is `true` (`if(K[37])`).

#### Diagonal movement:

Moving an element diagonally using simultaneously i.e. the <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> needs a compensation for the diagonal distance: `1 / Math.sqrt(2)` (0.7071..)

```js
const Player = {
  el: document.getElementById('player'),
  x: 200,
  y: 100,
  speed: 2,
  move() {
    this.el.style.transform = `translate(${this.x}px, ${this.y}px)`;
  }
};

const K = {
  fn(ev) {
    const k = ev.which;
    if (k >= 37 && k <= 40) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      K[k] = ev.type === "keydown"; // If is arrow
    }
  }
};

const update = () => {
  let dist = K[38] && (K[37] || K[39]) || K[40] && (K[37] || K[39]) ? 0.707 : 1;
  dist *= Player.speed;
  if (K[37]) Player.x -= dist;
  if (K[38]) Player.y -= dist;
  if (K[39]) Player.x += dist;
  if (K[40]) Player.y += dist;
  Player.move();
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', K.fn);
document.addEventListener('keyup', K.fn);

(function engine() {
  update();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(engine);
}());
```

```css
#player{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;  top: 0;
  width: 20px;  height: 20px;
  background: #000;  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
Click here to focus, and use arrows
<div id="player"></div>
```

or here's a slight remake using `new Set()` to keep record of the currently pressed keyboard keys, and `new Map()` to register functions for every pressed key:

```js
const Player = {
  el: document.querySelector("#player"),
  x: 200,
  y: 100,
  speed: 2,
  move() {
    this.el.style.translate = `${this.x}px ${this.y}px`;
  }
};

const getDistance = () => Player.speed * ((kbd.has("ArrowUp") || kbd.has("ArrowDown")) && (kbd.has("ArrowLeft") || kbd.has("ArrowRight")) ? 0.707 : 1);

// Watch pressed keyboard keys:
const kbd = new Set();
const handleArrowKeys = (evt) => {
  if (!keyActions.has(evt.key)) return; // Do nothing. Not a registered key
  evt.preventDefault(); // Prevent browser default action
  kbd[evt.type === "keydown" ? "add" : "delete"](evt.key); // Add or delete a key
};
addEventListener("keydown", handleArrowKeys);
addEventListener("keyup", handleArrowKeys);

// Register keyboard keys actions
// Set a desired function for every desired key:
const keyActions = new Map();
keyActions.set("ArrowRight", () => {
  Player.x += getDistance();
});
keyActions.set("ArrowLeft", () => {
  Player.x -= getDistance();
});
keyActions.set("ArrowUp", () => {
  Player.y -= getDistance();
});
keyActions.set("ArrowDown", () => {
  Player.y += getDistance();
});

const engine = () => {
  // Trigger a keyAction for pressed keys
  kbd.forEach((key) => keyActions.get(key)());
  Player.move();
  requestAnimationFrame(engine);
};

engine();
```

```css
#player { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 20px; height: 20px; background: #000; border-radius: 50%; }
```

```html
Click here to focus, and use arrow keys
<div id="player"></div>
```

Answer (score 9):

I messed around with a similar thing and here's a solution I came across that works.

```
setInterval(movePlane, 20);
var keys = {}

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    delete keys[e.keyCode];
});

function movePlane() {
    for (var direction in keys) {
        if (!keys.hasOwnProperty(direction)) continue;
        if (direction == 37) {
            $("#plane").animate({left: "-=5"}, 0);                
        }
        if (direction == 38) {
            $("#plane").animate({top: "-=5"}, 0);  
        }
        if (direction == 39) {
            $("#plane").animate({left: "+=5"}, 0);  
        }
        if (direction == 40) {
            $("#plane").animate({top: "+=5"}, 0);  
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fbFuW/220/)

The problem with the delay seems to be that most browsers will take the first input (on keyDown) and then they have half a second delay before running the functions over and over. If we don't recall the function on keydown, but rather have an interval checking an associative array where we store what keys are being held down, that seems to smooth out movement. It also allows for multiple keys to be pressed at once, which means diagonal movement. Then we'll remove the respective keys by using the keyup event.

In this solution you have two ways of managing the speed of the element you're moving.

1. The update frequency of the interval. (20ms in the demo above)
2. The pixel count per move of the plane. (5 in the demo above)

I find that 20 ms on the interval frequency gives you fairly smooth movement.

I realize that this is a really old thread, but I figured I'd contribute anyway.

Comment: Your image isn't working anymore, but if you paste any link to an image, the fiddle will work ... Nice example.

Comment: Updated the fiddle with a working image. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 2):

about that interval,

http://jsfiddle.net/fbFuW/21/

```
var leftDown, rightDown, upDown, downDown,leftKey,upKey,rightKey,downKey;
    var box = $("#plane");

function keye(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    var $key = e.keyCode;

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == left && $key != left) leftDown = true;
        if (e.keyCode == right && $key != right) rightDown = true;
        if (e.keyCode == down && $key != down) downDown = true;
        if (e.keyCode == up && $key != up) upDown = true;
    }).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == left) leftDown = false;
        if (e.keyCode == right) rightDown = false;
        if (e.keyCode == down) downDown = false;
        if (e.keyCode == up) upDown = false;
    });
    if (e.keyCode == left) {
        leftKey = true;
    }

    if (e.keyCode == up) {
        upKey = true;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == right) {
        rightKey = true;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == down) {
        downKey = true;
    }

}

$("body").keydown(function(){
   keye(event); 
});


$("body").keyup(function(e){
       if (e.keyCode == left) {
        leftKey = false;
    }

    if (e.keyCode == up) {
        upKey = false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == right) {
        rightKey = false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == down) {
        downKey = false;
    }
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (leftDown) {
        box.css('left', '-=5');
    }

    if (rightDown) {
        box.css('left', '+=5');
    }

    if (downDown) {
        box.css('top', '+=5');
    }

    if (upDown) {
        box.css('top', '-=5');
    }

    if (upKey) {
        box.css("top", "-=5");
    }
    if (rightKey) {
        box.css("left", "+=5");
    }
    if (downKey) {
        box.css("top", "+=5");
    }
    if (leftKey) {
        box.css("left", "-=5");
    }


},20);
```

Comment: +1 Thanks genesis! This looks pretty..... long! :) but it works... almost. There is still some stop-delay. Try to keep 'left' pressed and than fast switch to 'right'. The ship will stall. :\

Comment: @roXon: sorry, press F5. I have gotten some dummy if statements.

Comment: @roXon: got some progress, but it is flying around without approval! http://jsfiddle.net/fbFuW/17/

Comment: Your edit is not working genesis! (You look at my Question edit. So far the best I did)

Comment: In Mozilla the ship is NOT moving! P.S. in Chrome... it just RULEZ! :D

Comment: @roXon: damn. Yes, testing in Chrome. Try this one http://jsfiddle.net/genesis/fbFuW/31/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3144/discussion-between-genesis--and-roxon)

Comment: Tried to make work your Beautiful demo (the one that works in Cgrome) but with no success. Can't figure out where is the problem in what line/s.