# Keyboard input pause

Tags: javascript, input

I made a pretty basic demo, you press an arrow key and the square moves in that direction. One problem: when I first press the key, the square moves a little, pauses, then continues moving. How do I get rid of or work around the pause?

Code:

```js
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var p1 = document.getElementById("p1");
    var keys = [];
    var x = 25
    var y = 25
    
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      keys[e.keyCode] = true;
      update();
    });
    
    document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
      keys[e.keyCode] = false;
      update();
    });
    
    function update() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400)
      
      if(keys[40] == true) {
        y += 5
      }
      
      if(keys[38] == true) {
        y -= 5
      }
      
      if(keys[39] == true) {
        x += 5
      }
      
      if(keys[37] == true) {
        x -= 5
      }
      
      ctx.fillRect(x, y, 100, 100)
      
      console.log(keys);
    
      p1.innerText = "";
    
      for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (keys[i]) {
          p1.innerText += i + " | ";
        }
      }
    }
```

```html
    <canvas id='canvas' width='400' height='400'></canvas>
    <p id='p1'>testing</p>
```

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7320782/383904

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the `keydown` event is [continuously fired at different intervals in different browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087959/prevent-javascript-keydown-event-from-being-handled-multiple-times-while-held-do).

Instead of relying on the browser to send `keydown` from time to time, it's better to have your own update loop running at `60fps`, using [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) and each frame moving the box based on the keys pressed.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var p1 = document.getElementById("p1");
var keys = [];
var x = 25
var y = 25

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {  
  e.preventDefault(); // make sure this doesn't scroll the window
  keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});

function update() {
  //  Tell the browser to run again update when it is "free",
  // preferably at 60fps (actually your monitor's refresh rate)
  requestAnimationFrame(update);

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400)

  if(keys[40] == true) {
    y += 5
  }

  if(keys[38] == true) {
    y -= 5
  }

  if(keys[39] == true) {
    x += 5
  }

  if(keys[37] == true) {
    x -= 5
  }

  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 100, 100)

  p1.innerText = "";

  for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if (keys[i]) {
      p1.innerText += i + " | ";
    }
  }
}
update(); // Start running the loop at 60fps
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width='400' height='400'></canvas>
<p id='p1'>testing</p>
```

Note that the **distance** the box moves in a given amount of time **depends on your framerate**, so if the browser can't keep up at `60fps`  and only runs at `30fps`, `update` will be only called half of the times, so the box will only move half of the distance it would otherwise move at `60fps`. To learn more about animations and game update loops I recommend to read this [fix your timestep article](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/).

Comment: I also think `Event.preventDefault()` should be used in a browser environment - when using arrows. And a diagonal movement compensation should also be taken into account.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks for the suggestions, I added it to my answer.

Comment: I tried this code, but for some reason, it doe not run in Codepen. Do I need to add anything to make it run?

Comment: @ARCS2016 If you press "Run code snippet" above you should see it working.

Comment: Yeah nvm it's working now. I don't know why it didn't before. Thanks!