# How can I make an image move with arrow keys with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty new to javascript and have been trying to figure out how to make an image move. I've come up with this code and it kind of works but the image stops moving after a little bit. How do I fix this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #img {
                position: relative;
            }
        </style>
        <title>This is filler text</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is filler text</p>
        <img src="example.jpeg" length="100" width="100" id="img" />
        <script>
            document.onkeydown = function(event) {
                    switch (event.keyCode) {
                       case 37:
                      moveLeft();
                          break;
                       case 38:
                      moveUp();
                          break;
                       case 39:
                      moveRight();
                          break;
                       case 40:
                      moveDown();
                          break;
                    }
                };
                function moveLeft() {
                    document.getElementById("img").style.left += "5px";
                }
                function moveRight(){
                    document.getElementById("img").style.right += "5px";
                }
                function moveDown(){
                    document.getElementById("img").style.bottom += "5px";

                function moveUp(){
                    document.getElementById("img").style.top += "5px";
                }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Use CSS `transform` and `translate` instead of `left / top`
- Use [KeyboardEvent.**key**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead of the cryptic KeyboardEvent.keyCode

```js
const EL_img = document.querySelector("#img");
const pos = {x:0, y:0};

document.addEventListener("keydown", (ev) => {

  const dir = (ev.key.match(/(?<=^Arrow)\w+/)||[])[0];
  if (!dir) return; // Not an arrow key.
  
  ev.preventDefault(); // Prevent Browser scroll if overflow

  ({
    Left:  () => pos.x -= 5,
    Right: () => pos.x += 5,
    Up:    () => pos.y -= 5,
    Down:  () => pos.y += 5,
  }[dir])(); 
  
  EL_img.style.transform = `translate(${pos.x}px, ${pos.y}px)`
});
```

```css
#img {
  height: 40px;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<img id=img height=40 src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gh-CwvGkngFp6REJf46ncZD2p-nesp_4DmKOpSXGA=k-s420"   />
```

Here's another [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7320782/383904)

Answer (score 0):

Several things that you'll need to change:

- [Inline styles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) are going to return `string` values generally, so doing `+= "5px"` will [concatenate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition) your strings after the first keypress.
- [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) for an element uses `top / left / right / bottom` as offsets from those respected edges. So for this demo, you'll probably only want to adjust `left` and `right`, with *negative* `left` values pushing it to the left and *positive* pushing it to the right. Similar for `top`.

Because of these two, it'll probably be easier to have some separate Number variables for these offsets, operate on those variables directly, then update your inline style.

Here is an example of that:

```js
let left_offset = 0;
let top_offset = 0;
document.onkeydown = function (event) {
  let img = document.getElementById("img");
  switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      // Move left
      left_offset -= 5;
      break;
    case 38:
      // Move up
      top_offset -= 5;
      break;
    case 39:
      // Move right
      left_offset += 5;
      break;
    case 40:
      // Move down
      top_offset += 5;
      break;
  }
  img.style.left = `${left_offset}px`;
  img.style.top = `${top_offset}px`;
};
```

```css
#img {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<p>This is filler text</p>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" length="100" width="100" id="img" />
```